# decimal number convert to 16bit binary (C)

Tags: c, binary, bit

I want to convert a decimal number to a 16 bit binary number.
My code does not work at all but I am sure that I did the right steps.
Hope for some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int BIT = 16;

char binaer(int i) {
    char str[BIT];
    int j = 0;
    if(0 <= i && i <= 65535) {
        for(int j = 0; j < BIT + 1; j++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                str[j] = '0';
            } else {
                str[j] = '1';
            }
            i = i / 2;
        }
    }
    for(int x = BIT - 1; x >= 0; x--){
       printf("%c", str[x]);
    }
}

int main() {

    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);
    binaer(value);


    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Input: 16
Output: 00001000000000000
```

Comment: You must always end a C string with a zero.

Comment: One of your loops to `BIT` is not necessary. The one in `main` just prints out the result 16 times...

Comment: yeah the for loop in the main() was garbage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the loop in `main()` is meaningless. Call the function once and it's done.

`str` is a 16 element `char` array whose elements can be accessed via indices `0` to `15`. You accessed the `16`th one resulting in Undefined behavior.

`%s` in `printf` expects a null terminated `char` array. You didn't provide. That's Undefined Behavior again.

The function doesn't return anything. Make the return type `void`.

Inversely printing the binary form is being done. Make sure this is what you want. You should print the array in reverse. After the `for` loop is done you will print it.

```
for(int in = BIT-1; in >= 0; in--){
    printf("%c",str[in]);
}
printf("\n");
```

The way I printed it, if followed, the null terminator is not needed.

Comment: How can I reverse it?

Comment: @LenaBirke.: I said print it in reverse. You can loop in the char array and print character by character